# fputcsv large data cause "File not loaded completely"

Tags: php, csv, output, fputcsv

I have around 2m+ rows needed to output to `.csv` file because afaik it doesn't have any rows limit by using PHP and data from MySQL. However when the file was output, it shows "File not loaded completely" (refer **Image 1**).

After click OK, I saw the rows limit are there (refer **Image 2**) and below also I attach the script.

How to solve it so that it will output all the rows?

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

**Code**

```
<?php
$filename = 'StockOnHand_' . date('YmdHis') . '.csv';
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=hostname;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8mb4", $DB_USERNAME, $DB_PASSWORD);

$sql = " select col1, col2 from table ";

// Execute
try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $header = array(
        array('COL1', 'COL2')
    );

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    foreach ($header as $row) {
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }

    fclose($fp);
    $stmt = null;
    $conn = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    
}

exit;
?>
```

Comment: This looks like an Excel issue, not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of rows in an Excel spreadsheet is 1,048,576.

Your script has output all the rows, but you can't load that file in Excel.

[Reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)

Comment: Hi.. I'm loading it as .csv right? CSV has no rows limit right?

Comment: CSV has no row limit, but Excel does, regardless of the file format you read. You can't read a 2million row file with Excel.